# Is wordpress routed using index.php?

Tags: wordpress

I am on a project installing wordpress under zend framework.

Ref : [install WordPress with Zend, use Zend_Auth to allow view WordPress Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7356336/install-wordpress-with-zend-use-zend-auth-to-allow-view-wordpress-posts)

Long story short, I need to use zend login control the visiability of this blog.

Now I was suggested that if I can put the Zend Auth into wordpress index.php, then everthing will be solved.

So it comes to my idea that if all wordpress pages are routed through index.php then the next step for me is to find the way that wordpress accept zend auth.

Please any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the frontend of wordpress is routed using index.php.