# ZF Autoloader to load ancestor and requested class

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am integrating Zend Framework into an existing application. I want to switch the application over to Zend's autoloading mechanism to replace dozens of `include()` statements.

I have a specific requirement for the autoloading mechanism, though. Allow me to elaborate.

The existing application uses a core library (independent from ZF), for example:

```
/Core/Library/authentication.php
/Core/Library/translation.php
/Core/Library/messages.php
```

this core library is to remain untouched at all times and serves a number of applications. The library contains classes like

```
class ancestor_authentication { ... }
class ancestor_translation { ... }
class ancestor_messages { ... }
```

in the *application*, there is also a Library directory:

```
/App/Library/authentication.php
/App/Library/translation.php
/App/Library/messages.php
```

these includes extend the ancestor classes and are the ones that actually get instantiated in the application.

```
class authentication extends ancestor_authentication { }
class translation extends ancestor_translation { }
class messages extends ancestor_messages { }
```

usually, these class definitions are empty. They simply extend their ancestors and provide the class name to instantiate.

```
$authentication = new authentication();
```

The purpose of this solution is to be able to easily customize aspects of the application without having to patch the core libraries.

Now, the autoloader I need would have to be aware of this structure. When an object of the class `authentication` is requested, the autoloader would have to:

```
1. load  /Core/Library/authentication.php
2. load  /App/Library/authentication.php
```

My current approach would be creating a custom function, and binding that to `Zend_Loader_Autoloader` for a specific namespace prefix.

- Is there already a way to do this in Zend that I am overlooking? The accepted answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304323/integrating-external-scripts-with-zend-framework) kind of implies there is, but that may be just a bad choice of wording.
- Are there extensions to the Zend Autoloader that do this?
- Can you - I am new to ZF - think of an elegant way, conforming with the spirit of the framework, of extending the Autoloader with this functionality? I'm not necessary looking for a ready-made implementation, some pointers (This should be an extension to the `xyz` method that you would call like this...) would already be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extend what [Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453956/zf-autoloader-to-load-ancestor-and-requested-class/2454029#2454029) already pointed out, I'd create my own autoloader class that implements `Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Interface` and push that onto the `Zend_Loader_Autoloader`-stack.

```
class My_Autoloader implements Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Interface 
{
    public function autoload($class) 
    {
        // add your logic to find the required classes in here
    }
}

$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
// pushAutoloader() or unshiftAutoloader() depending on where 
// you'd like to put your autoloader on the stack
// note that we leave the $namespace parameter empty
// as your classes don't share a common namespace
$autoloader->pushAutoloader(new My_Autoloader(), '');
```

I wouldn't go with the `Zend_Loader` approach as, even though not deprecated yet, the new `Zend_Loader_Autoloader` seems to be best practice currently.

Answer (score 1):

See the [manual on Zend_Loader](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html):

> By default, the autoloader is configured to match the "Zend_" and "ZendX_" namespaces. If you have your own library code that uses your own namespace, you may register it with the autoloader using the registerNamespace() method.

```
$autoloader->registerNamespace('My_');
```

Note that the autoloader follows the ZF Naming Convention, so `Zend_Foo_Bar` will look in `Zend/Foo/Bar.php`.

However,

> You can also register arbitrary autoloader callbacks, optionally with a specific namespace (or group of namespaces). Zend_Loader_Autoloader will attempt to match these first before using its internal autoloading mechanism.

```
$autoloader->pushAutoloader(array('ezcBase', 'autoload'), 'ezc');
```

Another way would be to [create custom class Loader extending Zend_Loader](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.load.html) and then register it with:

```
Zend_Loader::registerAutoload('My_Loader');
```

ZF will then use this autoloader instead of the default one.

Comment: Cheers @Gordon, I'm going to go with the Zend_Loader_Autoloader approach shown by @Stefan in this case. As so often, I would like to be able to accept both answers. Ah well...