# Proper error handling in a custom Zend_Autoloader?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-autoloader

I'm building a custom autoloader based on Zend Framework's autoloading (related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453956/zf-autoloader-to-load-ancestor-and-requested-class)).

The basic approach, taken from that question, is

```
class My_Autoloader implements Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Interface 
{
    public function autoload($class) 
    {
        // add your logic to find the required classes in here
    }
}
```

and then binding the new autoloader class to a class prefix.

Now what I'm unsure about is how to handle errors inside the `autoload` method (for example, "class file not found") in a proper, ZF compliant way. I'm new to the framework, its conventions and style.

- Do I quietly return false and let the class creation process crash?
- Do I output an error or log message somehow (which would be nice to pinpoint the problem) and return false? If so, what is the Zend way of doing that?
- Do I trigger an error?
- Do I throw an exception? If so, what kind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the kind of error. I'd consider it a fatal error if a class cannot be loaded. Thus I'd throw an Exception, e.g.

```
class My_Autoloader_Exception extends Exception {}
```

You will find that ZF uses a lot of custom Exceptions on the package level and also [provides a class](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.exception.html) for this to extend from (though I'd consider this optional).

Incidentally, there is a usage example of `Zend_Exception` with their autoloader:

```
  try {
      // Calling Zend_Loader::loadClass() with a non-existant class will cause
      // an exception to be thrown in Zend_Loader:
      Zend_Loader::loadClass('nonexistantclass');
  } catch (Zend_Exception $e) {
      echo "Caught exception: " . get_class($e) . "\n";
      echo "Message: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
      // Other code to recover from the error
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

ZF itself uses two different approaches:

- `Zend_Loader` (the *old* autoloading mechanism) throws a `Zend_Exception` in case something's wrong
- `Zend_Loader_Autoloader` returns `false` when the used registered autoloader returns `false`

The `Zend_Loader_Autoloader` doesn't catch any exception thrown in the used autoloader to eventually your custom exception would bubble up through the `Zend_Loader_Autoloader`. I personally just return `false` in case I'm not able to load a requested class.